# Need some help getting a component in a multiple child instances of an abstract class

Tags: unity-game-engine, inheritance, abstract-class

---

Hiya - so i think i'm at a bit of a misunderstanding here with using abstract classes so if it isn't too much trouble i need someone to explain to me where i've gone wrong here;

---

So i have an abstract class structured like this:

```
 [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
 [RequireComponent(typeof(Collider2D))]
 
 public abstract class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {
     // Physics
     protected Rigidbody2D rb;
     protected Collider2D col;
 
     protected virtual void Awake(){
         // Physics
             rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
             col = this.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
             col.isTrigger = true;
     }
 }
```

---

Then a class inheriting it:

```
 public class Whizzer : Enemy {
         protected override void Awake(){
               // Physics
               rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
               rb.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic;
               rb.gravityScale = 0f;
 
               col = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
               col.isTrigger = true;
        }
 }
```

---

However the problem i'm having is that when i reference rb or col inside the Whizzer class it's (i think) accessing the variables defined in the abstract Enemy class - this results in only one instance of a gameobject with this script working at a time since the last script to run assigns their rigidbody and collider as the variables in the abstract Enemy class

My question is how can i create seperate instances of the variables rb and col for every Whizzer class instance created whilst keeping the variables desired inside the abstract enemy class?
Or if this is even the right way to go about doing this?

Thankyou in advance!

---

Answer (score 1):

They should be saparate. If you want a variable to be shared among all instances you should use "static" modifier. But you do not use that so each instance of Enemy (Whizzer is also an Enemy) should have it's own value for these fields. How do you know that they point to the same instances of collider and rigidbody?

About your implementation you are slightly missing the point:

```
public abstract class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    protected Rigidbody2D rb;
    protected Collider2D col;

    protected virtual void Awake(){        
         rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
         col = this.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
         col.isTrigger = true;
    }
}
```

Then a class inheriting it:

```
public class Whizzer : Enemy {
     protected override void Awake(){
           base.Awake();               
           rb.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic;
           rb.gravityScale = 0f; 
    }
}
```

That makes more sense imho, you should use base method in most cases instead of pasting the same chunk of code to override

Comment: "How do you know that they point to the same instances of collider and rigidbody?" - When I use `rb.velocity` within a fixed update in the `Whizzer class` only one gameobject with the `whizzer script` is affected the other just shoots off in a random direction as it's `rb.velocity` property is only accessed once and then (i'm assuming) reassigned by the other instances. 

As for the code that makes sense thankyou! and am i correct in assuming that when you modify rb in `Whizzer` it affects all other instances of `Whizzer classes` but not other classes inheriting the `Enemy class`?

Comment: The code for when i use `rb.velocity` is this:
```protected override void FixedUpdate(){ base.FixedUpdate(); rb.velocity = Player.phy.Velocity + VelOffset; }```

Where `Player.phy.Velocity` is a reference to my players velocity and `VelOffset` is just a Vector3

Comment: No, each instance of Enemy (no matter if its Whizzer, Wizzard, Orc etc) will have it's own value for Rigidbody and Collider in your case. How does your FixedUpdate in Enemy.cs look?

Comment: There's nothing in the FixedUpdate in `enemy.cs` at the minute (literally just `protected virtual void FixedUpdate(){}`) - `base.FixedUpdate()` is really just a placeholder whilst i was testing schtuff so it's really confusing me what's wrong here - maybe it's the `rb.velocity` variable itself? - although that seem unlikely...